# get json array in php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get some values from an json file in php. But i can't solve this issue.

**This is my php file:**

```
<?php

 // file_get_contents call instead
$str = '{
"volume": 0,
"mute": false,
"equalizer": {
    "bass": 3,
    "treble": 6,
    "loudness": true,
    "speechEnhancement": false,
    "nightMode": false
},
"currentTrack": {
    "artist": "kane",
    "title": "",
    "album": "",
    "albumArtUri": "",
    "duration": 0,
    "uri": "x-rincon-queue:RINCON_B8E93741470A01400#0",
    "type": "track",
    "stationName": ""
},
"nextTrack": {
    "artist": "",
    "title": "",
    "album": "",
    "albumArtUri": "",
    "duration": 0,
    "uri": ""
},
"trackNo": 0,
"elapsedTime": 0,
"elapsedTimeFormatted": "00:00:00",
"playbackState": "STOPPED",
"playMode": {
    "repeat": "none",
    "shuffle": false,
    "crossfade": false
},
"sub": {
    "gain": 0,
    "crossover": 0,
    "polarity": 0,
    "enabled": true
}
}';

// decode JSON
 $json = json_decode($str, true);


// get the data
$title = $json['volume'];

foreach ($json as $json) {

echo $json['currentTrack'][0]['artist'];
}

//echo it
echo $title;
```

I want to get the "volume" and "artist" in array"CurrentTrack" but i get this output any help?

```
NOTICE Undefined index: currentTrack on line number 63

NOTICE Undefined index: currentTrack on line number 63

WARNING Illegal string offset 'currentTrack' on line number 63

WARNING Illegal string offset 'artist' on line number 63
0
WARNING Illegal string offset 'currentTrack' on line number 63

WARNING Illegal string offset 'artist' on line number 63
S
NOTICE Undefined index: currentTrack on line number 63

NOTICE Undefined index: currentTrack on line number 63
0
```

I just want to 'get Kane 0' as output. But i don't see "kane" in the output and I can't get rid off the warnings and notices. any help ? Thnx

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You can use json_decode anyway.

Comment: `echo $json['currentTrack']['artist'];`

Comment: @BikashP yes i tried a lot but i can't get rid off those warnings and notices. or get the correct output I want

Comment: @JYoThI You *tried a lot*, but what did you try ? That's what we need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `no zero`th `index` just access like below

```
echo $json['currentTrack']['artist']."<br>"; 
echo $json['volume']."<br>";
```

**Note :** Here no need `foreach` .

Comment: Here no need `foreach`  @QuinnDonkers  just access it like my answer . without `foreach`

Comment: great that works ! thnx, but how can i set them under each other with some space?

Comment: just add the `<br>` tag ` echo $json['currentTrack']['artist']."<br>";
echo $json['volume']."<br>";`

Answer (score 0):

Try it a little smaller

```
$str = '{
"volume": 0,
"currentTrack": {
     "artist": "buddy"
}
}';

$json = json_decode($str, true);
echo $json['currentTrack']['artist'];
```

And build up

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
//JSON Decode 
$json = json_decode($str, true);
print $json['currentTrack']['artist'];
```

**Output:** kane

or

If you want print the **currentTrack** values use below code:

```
//JSON Decode 
$json = json_decode($str, true);
$currentTrack = $json['currentTrack'];
foreach ($currentTrack as $data){
    echo $data."\n";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $array = json_decode($str, true);



print_r$array);

array:11 [▼
  "volume" => 0
  "mute" => false
  "equalizer" => array:5 [▶]
  "currentTrack" => array:8 [▶]
  "nextTrack" => array:6 [▶]
  "trackNo" => 0
  "elapsedTime" => 0
  "elapsedTimeFormatted" => "00:00:00"
  "playbackState" => "STOPPED"
  "playMode" => array:3 [▶]
  "sub" => array:4 [▶]
]
```

`echo $array['volume']` // you can do it becasue `volume` is not containt an array

`echo $array['mute']` // this is also valid

**But**

`echo $array['equalizer']` // **this is not valid.** Becuase `'equalizer` key is contain an array.

That's why you can't see the output of whole array by for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<?php

$str = '{
"volume": 0,
"mute": false,
"equalizer": {
    "bass": 3,
    "treble": 6,
    "loudness": true,
    "speechEnhancement": false,
    "nightMode": false
},
"currentTrack": {
    "artist": "kane",
    "title": "",
    "album": "",
    "albumArtUri": "",
    "duration": 0,
    "uri": "x-rincon-queue:RINCON_B8E93741470A01400#0",
    "type": "track",
    "stationName": ""
},
"nextTrack": {
    "artist": "",
    "title": "",
    "album": "",
    "albumArtUri": "",
    "duration": 0,
    "uri": ""
},
"trackNo": 0,
"elapsedTime": 0,
"elapsedTimeFormatted": "00:00:00",
"playbackState": "STOPPED",
"playMode": {
    "repeat": "none",
    "shuffle": false,
    "crossfade": false
},
"sub": {
    "gain": 0,
    "crossover": 0,
    "polarity": 0,
    "enabled": true
}
}

';

$json = json_decode($str, true);

$volume = $json['volume'];
$currentTrack_artist = $json['currentTrack']['artist'];

//you dont have this value
//$currentTrack_artist = $json['currentTrack']['volume'];

echo $volume."<br>";
echo $currentTrack_artist;
```

But you dont have value of volume in currentTrack array. i wrote that as comment in code.